# ImageMagick convert with PHP exec path

Tags: imagemagick

I have successfully installed ImageMagick on my local Windows 7 PC. And test the convert C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\a.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\b.jpg

But when I am trying to this from a PHP file named C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php
with the code

```
<?php
    exec("C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\a.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\b.jpg", $output, $return);
?>
```

It does not work. The a.jpg file exists. and I am using the browser to run the index.php file with the path `http://localhost/test/index.php`

$output is blank and $return is 1.

However when I use

```
<?php
    exec("C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert", $output, $return);
?>
```

I get the output as Imagemagick version...
The same output if I run the command "convert" in the command prompt.
I am using xamp in windows 7.
I have searched a lot, but the issues mentioned there is not which I face.

Because when I used only "convert" in PHP exec I got the output.

So could not understand what is the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been banging my head against this issue for several hours now.

```
exec("C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\a.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\b.jpg", $output, $return);
```

This code should work fine, just one issue, try running "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\a.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\b.jpg" **without the quotes** in a command prompt and you get 'C:\Program' is not recognized.
Need to quote the path to the convert exe.

Try this `exec('"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert" C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\a.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\test\images\b.jpg', $output, $return);`

It should work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered but I was banging my head against a wall for 5 hours last night trying to do this.

I think it's worth noting that if any of your paths have spaces in them (the executable, input file and output file) then they need to each be quoted separately:

i.e.

`exec('"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\convert" "C:\Documents\Web Dev\test.jpg" -resize 50x50 "C:\Documents\Web Dev\output.jpg"', $output, $return);`

I hope this helps to save 5 hours of someone else's life.